# Magento 2 Uncaught TypeError: Constr is not a constructor when returning functions on Knockout Js

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

i'm trying to get functions from a JS file in a Knockou file, like this:

quote.js

```
define(['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko','Vendor_GetQuote/js/ajax-request'], function ($, Component, ko, ajaxrequest) {
    'use strict';
```

And I try to access like this

```
ajaxrequest.functionA();
ajaxrequest.functionB();
```

With just one function it works, but with 2 or more it does not.

This is my ajax-request.js file

```
define(
    [
        'jquery'
    ],
    function(
        $
    ) {
        'use strict';

        var methods = {
            functionA: function() {
                console.log('This is from module A, functionA');
            },
    
            functionB: function() {
                console.log('This is from module A, function B');
            }
        };
    
        return methods;
     }
);
```

This is the error I'm getting:
Uncaught TypeError: Constr is not a constructor

Can someone orient me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `defined` use `require` when adding your javascript code like this:

```
require(
    [
        'jquery'
    ],
    function(
        $
    ) {
        'use strict';

        var methods = {
            functionA: function() {
                console.log('This is from module A, functionA');
            },
    
            functionB: function() {
                console.log('This is from module A, function B');
            }
        };
    
        return methods;
     }
);
```

This might causing the problem.
Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi, It did not work, I added require to my ajax-request.js also tried the require on quote.js